# Configuring apache webserver to view default page over the web publicly by using ip address(dynamic)

Tags: linux, apache, webserver, linux-mint

I am new to configuring apache webserver(this is my first time) and over the last few days i have been trying to configure apache so as to view the default page over the internet.I have been successful partially in being able to view the default page over local host on the network. The problem really comes over when I try to view the page over the public ip of the server.Every time i try the page reports a time out and/or an error in connection, so I have increased the time out from 300 to 3000(the issue remains). I have searched extensively over the internet and based on the findings i have configured apache to grant all connections, i have also configured the firewall on my linux system to allow incoming & outgoing. Further I have configured my dad's huawei hotspot e55** series as mentioned in the link here https://portforward.com/huawei/ . I have also tried to configure my internet connection for port forward from external to the internal ip however what i observe is that after i do that my internet connection seems to get disabled and I would have to delete the connection and add another one.At this point it looks like that I might be missing out something here and I believe a little help from the apache experts might just help me achieve my goal to view the default apache web page over the web using the system (public)ip(using whatismyip on google search).

Comment: you need to enable port forwarding from within your router configuration as you have also mentioned, can you please add some details what port forwarding configuration have you done?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: I  tried this-->  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0EwlThnVf1E but that seems to disable my internet connection so had to delete it.

Comment: @jww based on your exp,which site do you suggest I ask this qs?

Answer (score 0):

I think the public ip provided by your ISP cannot be used for hosting the website on the internet please contact your ISP to get a public IP that can host websites over the internet , or get a cloud hosting server.